# Clear cart via code/admin

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, quote

I want to empty my cart, because I made a mistake. I can't empty my cart now using the 'clear cart' button, so I want to force it to empty.

I already used this code on my `view.phtml` page:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->truncate()->save();
```

But that resulted in a 404 page. **Is there a way to force my cart to empty, via code or the admin?**

Btw a module that allows you to force everyone's cart empty (only in dev mode) would be lovely haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A module that allows you to force everyone's cart empty (only in dev
>   mode) would be lovely

If you want something that simple I reckon you can just run the following on your database:

```
TRUNCATE sales_flat_quote;
```

**WARNING** : only do that on your dev environment, this will delete all the carts.